# AWS Lambda: mount S3 files

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Because of lots of dependencies my ML code is not working inside Lambda.
1. Is there any way to load shared object inside lambda 
2. Can we mount external file system inside lambda.

Answer (score 0):

We have used AWS Athena and Redshift Spectrum for our ML / Neural Networks training.

You can use [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) and query selective records for your ML training. This will work for any large set.

If you are looking for performance in your queries, would recommend an external table with [Redshift Spectrum](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/spectrum/)

Both of the above technologies will mount S3 files to them and let you access it quickly and selectively with SQL queries.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think it will work, ML modules requires certain set of lib which **must**  be loaded in memory so it can work.  Only solution I can think of is AWS allowing Lambda to be created from our Docker Container. That way we can have all dependencies loaded up in container.

Comment: Checkout Amazon SageMaker. It can read not just from the above but tons of other data sources. ML just needs data, you can read it from any data source from anywhere. Performance will matter for huge dataset.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html. Will help you run query inside lambda.